# Silenium webdriver using Java: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException:

Tags: java, xpath

I am using Webdriver and trying to click on a link (Billing) which further has a dropdown(My Quotes). To locate billing and then to click on My Quotes link, I am using the below code:

```
String xp = "//*[@id='Primary_Navbar-Billing']/a";  // With this xpath I can search on my Firefox browser but using the same in my code gives me an error: 

WebElement menu = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xp));


    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    // Initiate mouse action using Actions class
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);    

    // move the mouse to the earlier identified menu option
    builder.moveToElement(menu).build().perform();

    //identify menu option from the resulting menu display and click
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("My Quotes")).click();
```

I am getting an error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException:

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

you can try those 3 options:

- Add a Thread.sleep(YourMilliSecondesTime); before your click(); action.
- Use Xpath instead By.linkText to find your link, Xpath is ALWAYS the better option.
- or try this: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='YOURLINKTEXTEHERE']")).click()); if for any reason you don't have a good xpath for this element.

Hope this will help. :)

Comment: or explicity wait or use Id. Many Options.